# How to pass Mat-Select Value to a header in API Call

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have an API which requires country code in header along with authorization token and Bearer.
I am able to fetch mat-select value in my component file.
However my api header and token are being set in service file.
Can anyone help me figure out how do I pass the value of mat-select from component to service file?

For now I am hard coding the country Value as 'au' but I want it to set it as per mat-select dropdown value.

Code to fetch mat-select value in Component File:

```
onCountrySelection() {
console.log(this.countryValue);
sessionStorage.setItem('countryCode', this.countryValue);
}
```

API in service Class File;

```
uploadConfig(templateName, JsonBody) {
const header = new HttpHeaders().set(
  'Authorization',
  'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token'),
).set(
  'country',
  'au'
);
return this.httpClient.post(
  this.localUrl + '/pattern/' + templateName + '/flow', JsonBody,
  { headers: header }
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add additional parameter to your signature of API method:

```
uploadConfig(templateName, JsonBody, countryCode) {

    const header = new HttpHeaders().set(
      'Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token'),
    ).set(
      'country', countryCode
    );
    return this.httpClient.post(
        this.localUrl + '/pattern/' + templateName + '/flow', JsonBody, { headers: header }
        );
}
```

And then when you are calling service just send `countryValue`:

```
uploadConfig(,,this.countryValue);
```